# firebase_auth 0.18.3 upgrade breaks my project

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm using flutter on ios, and I was using firebase_auth 0.16.1 (with firebase_core) 0.4.4, and my project mostly worked, but my users needed to go through authorization every time.  The phone refused to remember anything about previous login attempts, which has now become an issue.

So after some digging, I found that Firebase_auth has put into place some upgrades that (should) resolve this issue, however, my implementation is obviously lacking.

So I upgraded to firebase_auth 0.18.3 with firebase_core 0.5.2, which apparently needs an initialization step first.  I copied that code directly from their website, but all it does is give me an error.

So this is what I've got right now.

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

class PreValidation extends StatelessWidget {

  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
    future: _initialization,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        print("Uh Oh");
        return;
      }
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        pretest();
        return;
      }

    }
    );
  }
```

I'm getting an error saying that the futurebuilder is returning null.  I know I can't, but I'm not exactly sure what this is supposed to be returning.  If I knew what kind of object it's looking for that would be a start.

My problem is that I really only need to run this code at the beginning, before my program even starts, and if it succeeds, go into the main portion of my app, if it fails, go through authentication.  And this entire class set-up from firebase really is set-up to be a base class, which really is not what I'm doing here.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating you `main()` function (tested and working on Flutter 1.22, firebase_auth: ^0.18.1+1 & firebase_core: ^0.5.0:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      home: FutureBuilder(
        future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            print('error');
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
             pretest();
             return;
          }

          return Loading();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```